# How can I check chefspec/unit test for following code of my recipe

Tags: unit-testing, chef-infra, chef-recipe, cookbook, chefspec

I am trying to write the chefspec/unit test for my recipe. I am facing problem. I need to write the unit test case for below code. If I comment the last statement of my code, the test execute successfully but I have to catch that statement too as its the proper way to write. Thanks for helping.

```
powershell_script 'Delete ISO from temp directory' do
    code <<-EOH
            [System.IO.File]::Delete("#{iso_path}")
            [System.IO.File]::Delete("#{config_path}")
            EOH
    guard_interpreter :powershell_script
    only_if { File.exists?(iso_path)}
end
```

Comment: As I understand, you are trying to delete some files. Chef has `file` resource for that, you do not need powershell.

Comment: @DracoAter I want to delete the ISO from the temporary directory only if it exists. I have used powershell resource for unit testing of this block and it works fine but I have to catch the condition too in order to write unit test properly

Comment: That's exactly what `file` resource does. It deletes the file, if the file exists. You should always prefer existing idempotent resources (like file, directory, template) to non-idempotent (like execute, bash, powershell_script).

Answer (score 0):

So to start with, your code doesn't make sense. You have a `guard_interpreter` set but your guard clause is a Ruby code block, not a command string. Other than that, just test it like anything else. If you mean specifically how to test both the file existing and not existing, you would use `rspec-mocks` to set up `File.exists?` to return a canned value.

Answer (score 0):

First of all. If all you need is to delete a file, and according to the code that is the case, you should use `file` resource.

```
[iso_path, config_path].each do |path|
  file path do
    action :delete
  end
end
```

`File` is idempotent resource. Which means Chef checks for you, if the resource should be changed. In this case Chef will delete the file, only if that exists.

`Powershell_script` (and all the other `script` resources) are non-idempotent. Which means, you have check yourself, if the resource should be executed, by providing a `guard`. Guard is `only_if` or `not_if` block. You should remove `guard_interpreter :powershell_script` line, because you are actually writing ruby in the guard.

```
powershell_script 'Delete ISO from temp directory' do
  code <<-EOH
    [System.IO.File]::Delete("#{iso_path}")
    [System.IO.File]::Delete("#{config_path}")
    EOH
  only_if { File.exists?(iso_path) }
end
```

Now to testing. Testing `file` resource is easy, as I understand you already can do that. But testing `powershell_script` is harder: you must stub the `File.exists?(iso_path)` call. You can do it like that:

```
describe 'cookbook::recipe' do
  context 'with iso file' do
    let! :subject do
      expect( ::File ).to receive( :exists? ).with( '<iso_path_variable_value>' ).and_return true
      allow( ::File ).to receive( :exists? ).and_call_original
      ChefSpec::Runner.new( platform: 'windows', version: '2008R2' ).converge described_recipe
    end

    it { shold run_powershell_script 'Delete ISO from temp directory' }
  end

  context 'without iso file' do
    let! :subject do
      expect( ::File ).to receive( :exists? ).with( '<iso_path_variable_value>' ).and_return false
      allow( ::File ).to receive( :exists? ).and_call_original
      ChefSpec::Runner.new( platform: 'windows', version: '2008R2' ).converge described_recipe
    end

    it { shold_not run_powershell_script 'Delete ISO from temp directory' }
  end
end
```

Do you see how much more work you have to do comparing to testing `file` resource?